# How to publish Android module to GitHub and use it as a library?

Tags: java, android, git, github, gradle

I have an Android project that contains 3 modules:

- app module - Main module with which I build the APK
- feature module - Contains code for a specific feature
- common module - A module that both "app" and "feature" depend on, mainly to share content between them two

Currently all 3 of these modules are in the same project and the same Github repo.
How can I push "feature" and "common" each into their own private repositories and include them in the main project (than contains only "app") as libraries?

Comment: The Origin/Location of the source is irrelevant to AndroidStudio or your Android Project in general. What you likely want to do is use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to keep track and include the other two repositories. Keep in mind that git sub modules are the best thing that can happen to this problem, while at the same time *the worst thing that can happen* to this problem...

Comment: ..if you want to keep the three *completely separated* then you can publish the libraries as artifacts in maven or similar and use them as regular dependencies by including them in your gradle configuration for your 'app'. I have used [this plugin](https://github.com/vanniktech/gradle-maven-publish-plugin) to publish in the past. It adds a `./gradlew publish ...` task that does most of the work for you.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini this is a private repository I can't publish anywhere. My question is, with git submodules how can I manage versions of the different modules? because submodule is just another repo. Another question, both "app" and "feature" depend on "common" module, should I add "common" as a submodule to both the "app" and "feature" projects?

Comment: Git/Submodules/Versions: git submodules just point to a commit/branch in a repo (to simplify), so *you have to* commit in your main repo an "update". You go to your submodule, update/etc. that updates where your parent repo is "pointing at". As for the references, it depends how your project is currently structured, but remember that the fact that they are submodules changes nothing in regards to your project's structure. In your example... well you'll have a common submodule and both app/feature will have it as a dependency, but I'd say "app" is the main and common/feature are submodules.

Answer (score 0):

You should clone this Github repo to a new. And next remove all unnecessary :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).